# Как пробросить тип компонента-дженерика в другой компонент?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-типы

Необходимо сделать компонент-обертку/HOC для компонента (дженерик!) из сторонней библиотеки, чтобы у него тип пропсов был такой-же как и у оборачиваемого компонента и он так же являлся дженериком.

#### Псевдокод:

```
import VendorComponent from '@vendorLibrary';

type Entity = {
  id: number,
  name: string;
  anything: object;
}

// Сам компонент используется следующим образом 
<VendorComponent<Entity>
  valueKey="id" // keyof Entity
  // other props
/>
```

```
// HOC
type VendorComponentType = typeof VendorComponent;
type Props = React.ComponentProps<VendorComponentType>;

export const WithCustomOptions = (component: React.ComponentType<Props>) => {
  const Component = component;
  return (props: Props) => {
    const customProperty = {
      // ...
    };
    return <Component {...props} someProperty={customProperty} />;
  };
};
```

```
// Wrapper component
const WrapperComponent = (props: Props) => {
  return <VendorComponent {...props} />;
};

export default WithCustomOptions(WrapperComponent);
```

Проблема возникает, при использовании WrapperComponent

```
<WrapperComponent
  valueKey="id" // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  // other props
/>
```

Хотелось бы прокинуть тип пропсов так, чтобы WrapperComponent можно было использовать как дженерик. То есть

```
<WrapperComponent<Entity>
  valueKey="id"
  // other props
/>
```

Изначально планировал типы описать так:

```
type VendorComponentType = typeof VendorComponent;
type Props = React.ComponentProps<VendorComponentType<Entity>>; // ошибка! VendorComponentType не является дженериком
```

Возможно ли это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true&ts=4.0.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJZFiYARAeQFk5tcCj0YBaAE1zID0AuFwA0XUkJHjyAOxhIomdEjgA1JLL5QAwrkizNMAAo4wAZzgBvOAEcA7igBccczCjBZAczgBfUgA2SPAaWtB64BCG8i4APAAqAHwAFGAuodoRBkamEBZwAGRw8QCUcAC8iXAosgCegcFwAOpQKGBgillRRnFqcEgAHgpalskAdBO2LjW1ANoAumWV1XWixSlgZuYuxiitIMGK5rFqibMADPOFxUtVM5LCYhIZ4frd8hVwsgCuAQHVlnuLTaHV0b2i8HKX1%20-xQgLqD2kEikT1IMFqHTgAFF5MB0Z8rKQ4MS4MAeC4fiAAEaKUREkmyFAHAD8LjcHm8dJJK1qMAAFp4vKy4BAqQArJAYOn%20FEyWUSeJYgDK8RchO5AG4NfTiSdNJlwUZYjiYHjalUHChyvh8KSeOUrABGR2%20OACRI67lwLWe2LA9qdQ3yWLojoQTDqfWvSIQtZWXwWxzW23uz2a7Xcv2tANgmNGOAhjFIcORsK57LyNYms2Jq02u0O52u1Nekk%20-ykf2gtWeoLwLyaLuKOI6fpDfWjCZjKY8ha3HkpLoQlw6W5pkkJDZbHZ7JmHKDHUPFiNLoxnS7XUoVO4I7nyz337kD2RDqCfU8fZbq1twPvNbOgh%20MBxEkqTbnAuz7Puh5FiWQHnlcRRXss9w-v%20IKBnmn5wJseSWMssRAdYU64RYzaJBmP5EDA3xQLI6E5kBnq%20JRxKPiS7HEoqKo9mhaBRG4DGgp8z6vskLzlu8MAlOurY%20mhWYYVAxq4uitbJg2VjnORzGkL4QA)

```
interface VendorComponentProps { qwa: string }
let VendorComponent: <T>(p: VendorComponentProps & T) => any
let WrapperComponent: <V extends (...q: any[]) => any, T>(props: Parameters<V>[0] & T) => any
// -,-
VendorComponent = null as any
WrapperComponent = null as any
// -,-
type Entity = {
    id: number,
    name?: string,
    anything?: object,
}
TEST: {
    <VendorComponent<Entity> qwa='' id={11} />;;
    <WrapperComponent<typeof VendorComponent, {}> qwa='' />;;
    <WrapperComponent <typeof VendorComponent, Entity> qwa='' id={11} />;;
}
Wrapper: {
    let genWrapper: <C extends (...q: any[]) => any>(Component: C) =>
        <T>(props: Parameters<typeof Component>[0] & T) => any
    // -,-
    genWrapper = Component => {
        let WrapperComponent: <T>(props: Parameters<typeof Component>[0] & T) => any
        WrapperComponent = props => <Component {...props} />;
        return WrapperComponent
    };
    // -,-
    TEST: {
        const Wrapper = genWrapper(VendorComponent);;
        <Wrapper<Entity> qwa='' id={0} />;;
    }
}
```